# Is ExpressVPN trying to install malware on my PC?

Tags: malware, anti-virus, trojan, kaspersky

I have been using ExpressVPN for a while. Today when I was trying to update it to the latest version (10.36.0.4), Kaspersky detected the following trojan:

*HEUR:Trojan.Win64.Reincarnation.gen*

Kaspersky's report doesn't say much, and I couldn't find any useful information on the web.

```
Component: File Anti-Virus
Result description: Detected
Type: Trojan
Precision: Partially
Threat level: High
Object type: File
Object name: nssm.exe
Object path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\ExpressVPN\SetupTools
```

Here is the download source: https://www.expressvpn.com/clients/windows/expressvpn_windows_10.36.0.4_release.exe

Scanning the installer file with Kaspersky, [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/4b5f66eb919561bf503f7f1cc5c4a19ff959824f1832bdd2245cd51891b98c0d?nocache=1), hybrid-analysis.com, and Intezer did not find anything.

The trojan can only be detected during the installation and Kaspersky causes the process to get canceled.

I have already installed this version on another system that doesn't have Kaspersky or other antivirus system. Should I be worried? How can I tell if the other PC that doesn't have antivirus is infected or not?

Comment: Going by the name, this is [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/download), the Non-Sucking Service Manager. It is legitimate (good!) software. // I question ExpressVPN’s software dev practices in requiring it though. Where it ends up, too.

Comment: Probably a false positive, report this to ExpressVPN

Answer (score 1):

This is what ExpressVPN say about the subject on their Twitter page
[Today we’ve been asked questions about NSSM aka nssm.exe, what it is and how we use it](https://twitter.com/expressvpn/status/1485176917490040833):

> ExpressVPN uses NSSM to help make sure that if something goes wrong with a service that helps run your VPN connection, it restarts promptly so that you stay protected. It doesn't do anything else.

They also say :

> NSSM is a component that monitors running services and restarts them in case they stop running for any reason. Its codebase is open-source (https://git.nssm.cc/nssm/nssm), enabling anyone to ensure it isn’t doing anything unexpected.

The usage of NSSM is by design. This is open-source software and not
malware.

This is a false positive by Kaspersky.
As long as this is not corrected by Kaspersky Support, you probably
cannot install ExpressVPN.

You might be able to add to Kaspersky on your computer an exception
for the folder
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\ExpressVPN\`
and for the installation folder of NSSM, if you wish to re-enable
the Kaspersky run-time protection.